# How to configure custom DNS server with Docker?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, docker

I need to add a few lines to `/etc/hosts` for my web-app to work inside a Docker container.

Docker's `/etc/hosts` is read-only.

I'm trying to use dnsmasq:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# ...
RUN apt-get install -y -q dnsmasq
RUN echo 'listen-address=127.0.0.1' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
RUN echo 'resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
RUN echo 'conf-dir=/etc/dnsmasq.d' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
RUN echo 'user=root' >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
RUN echo 'nameserver 8.8.8.8' >> /etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
RUN echo 'nameserver 8.8.4.4' >> /etc/resolv.dnsmasq.conf
RUN echo 'address="/mydomain/127.0.6.1"' >> /etc/dnsmasq.d/0hosts
RUN service dnsmasq start
```

However, I can't get Docker to use my DNS server:

```
$ docker --dns=127.0.0.1 run my/container cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

What am I missing?

Configuration:

- OS X 10.9.4
- Docker version 1.1.0, build 79812e3
- boot2docker Client version: v1.1.0, Git commit: 7e20d36

Answer (score 17):

`--dns` works for `docker run` but not for `docker build`. So better solution is to adjust the settings globally with

```
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns=my-private-dns-server-ip --dns=8.8.8.8"
```

On Ubuntu I put this line into `/etc/default/docker`

Comment: Note that `/etc/default/docker` file is not used when docker daemon is executed, you should modify `daemon.json` config file. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file

Answer (score 11):

What I missing is that I messed up the order of options and arguments. If I specify `--dns` after `run`, everything works fine.

```
$ docker run --dns=127.0.0.1 my/container cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Doh.

Comment: This doesn't work however — dnsmasq is down...

Comment: You can also use the `--dns` option more then once. For example `docker run --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 127.0.0.1 my/container`